# css: easier way to write: div.markup h1,div.markup h2,div.markup h3{color:#f00;}?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there an easier way of writing this?

```
<style type=text/css>
div.markup h1,div.markup h2,div.markup h3,div.markup h4{color:#f00;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is no. It'd be nice to be able to do `div.markup (h1,h2,h3,h4)` but the current spec doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. External CSS pre-compilers like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) offer alternative syntax, so this should work:

```
div.markup
 {
   h1,h2,h3,h4 { color: #F00; }

 }
```

It's not possible in normal CSS, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easier way to write that in CSS.

You could look into using something like [{less}](http://lesscss.org/) to process style sheets, which would enable you to write it as:

```
div.markup {
  h1, h2, h3, h4 { color: #f00; }
}
```